# Git: ignore changes to tracked file as long as it's untouched

Tags: git, workflow

I have a file that is kind of bugging me during development. It's a poller (there are several of them actually) that every x milliseconds will send out an AJAX request and they are filling up the network view of my browser.

So basically what I want to do is temporarily increase the timeout interval of these pollers, however that will have them show up in git as changed files of course.

The files are rarely touched during development, however it's not guaranteed that there will never be changes.

So I experimented with `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree`, but it does't really do what I want. It is okay for changes upstream, but not for local changes *other than* the changes I made to the timeouts.

Basically what I want to do is:

1. Change the timeouts (in this case)
2. Say something like assume-unchanged *unless there are other changes to this file*
3. Handle upstream changes properly

Is there a way to do this? For example is there a way to let `--assume-unchange` be valid as long as the timestamp of a file didn't change for example. Or better yet if the patch between *original* -> *changes due to (1)* changes?

Comment: is this "timeout" a hardcoded value you change in the file ? Is using an environment variable an option ?

Comment: Working but inconvinient solution is to commit that change, and than remove that commit with some rebase (`rebase -i` or `rebase --onto`). Did you tried that? I would suppose `--assume-unchanged` is the next step (it was for me), but maybe not in your case. Of course you have to be careful to not push this commit.

Comment: @ThongKuah Yeah it's hardcoded in the file and no there is not really an option to use an environment variable instead :-(

Comment: @Frax no I didn't try that, but with all the switching of branches that will probably not work that well.